# how can i get checkbox value after clicking button

Tags: c#, asp.net

checkbox are created dynamically.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\Faraz\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Assignment_3_i130316\Assignment_3_i130316\bin\Products.xml");
    var goals = doc.Element("FTSRecord").Elements("Approval_PickDrop");
    var array = goals.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();

    int rowCnt = 0;
    int rowCtr;
    foreach (var b in array)
    {
        rowCnt++;
    }

    for (rowCtr = 1; rowCtr <= rowCnt; rowCtr++)
    {
        TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
        Table1.Rows.Add(tRow);
        for (int cellCtr = 1; cellCtr <= 2; cellCtr++)
        {
            // Create a new cell and add it to the row.
            TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
            tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
            if (cellCtr == 1)
            {
                tCell.Text = array[rowCtr - 1];
                tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
            }
            else
            {
              CheckBox c = new CheckBox();
              c.ID = "ID" + cellCtr;
              tCell.Controls.Add(c);
            }
        }                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Request.Form with the **name** of your checkbox

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Change Checkbox cell ID :: **c.ID = "ID_" + rowCtr;**

After click on button you get Table1 and iterate each row and get checkbox cell value for each row on respect of its ID **c.ID = "ID_" + rowCtr;** split Id with'_' get its array index position and the checkbox checked status tells its value.